# Почему у второго элемента не открывается настройка цвета?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Суть: Делаю настройку цвета двух элементов формы. Для этого использую небольшой плагин выбора цвета.

Проблема: При клике на воторой элемент цвет не появляется окошечко редактирования цвета, а на первом появляется без проблем.

Вопрос: Как решить данную проблему?

Html Код элементов:

```
<div>
  <div style="float: left;"><input type="text" name="color" id="color" style="width: 100px;" value="<?=$myrow_fss['background_color_form'];?>"></div>
  <div id="colorprivew" data-target="#color-picker" data-element="#form-fb-popup" style="float: right; width: 28px;height:29px; margin-right:51px; background-color: <?=$myrow_fss['background_color_form'];?>; border: 1px solid #333;cursor: pointer"></div>
</div>
  <br>
<div>
  <div style="clear:both;float: left;"><input type="text" name="color" id="color" style="width: 100px;" value="<?=$myrow_fss['text_color_form'];?>"></div>
  <div id="colorprivew" data-target="#color-picker" data-element="#color-picker" style="float: right; width: 28px;height:29px; margin-right:51px; background-color: <?=$myrow_fss['text_color_form'];?>; border: 1px solid #333;cursor: pointer"></div>
</div>
```

Код окошечка изменения цвета:

```
<div id="color-picker" class="cp-default left">
    <div class="ucrmicon close-item close-color">X</div>
    <div class="picker-wrapper">
      <div id="picker" class="picker"></div>
      <div id="picker-indicator" class="picker-indicator"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide-wrapper">
      <div id="slide" class="slide"></div>
      <div id="slide-indicator" class="slide-indicator"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Js код:

```
var typeleadsColorElement = undefined;
var ColorElement = undefined;
var slide = document.getElementById('slide');
var picker = document.getElementById('picker');
var slideIndicator = document.getElementById('slide-indicator');
var pickerIndicator = document.getElementById('picker-indicator');
//var colorInput = document.getElementById('new_status_color');

cp = ColorPicker(slide, picker, function(hex, hsv, rgb, mousePicker, mouseSlide) {
    ColorPicker.positionIndicators(slideIndicator, pickerIndicator, mouseSlide, mousePicker);
    if(typeleadsColorElement){      
        $(typeleadsColorElement).css('backgroundColor', hex);       
        $('' + ColorElement + '').css('backgroundColor', hex);  
    }
});

$('#colorprivew').on('click', function (event) {
    // Получаем ID блока, который нужно показать
    var elem = $(this).data("target");  
    ColorElement = $(this).data("element");
    typeleadsColorElement = $(this);    
    // Показываем блок
    $(this).after($(elem));
    $(elem).slideDown(500);
    //return '';
});

$('.close-color').bind('click', function (event) {
    // Получаем ID блока, который нужно показать // Скрываем блок
    $('#color-picker').slideUp(500);
});
```

Comment: Сделайте `colorprivew` не `id`, а классом и соответственно в onclick тоже сделайте класс `$('.colorprivew').on('click'`   И должно заработать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы хотите, чтобы какое-либо событие срабатывало при клике на множестве элементах, а не на одном конкретном, то следует использовать селектор по классу
(обозначается точкой). А у вас у элементов стоит селектор `id`. Его следует присваивать только одному конкретному элементу. Так как он должен быть уникальным для элемента.

Соответственно у дивов, надо убрать `id="colorprivew"`  и добавить `class="colorprivew"`

В обработчике `onclick` вместо

`$('#colorprivew').on('click'`

должно быть, соответственно

`$('.colorprivew').on('click'`

Comment: спасибо. сразу не сообразил.